# <a> link in a <li> doesn't cover the entire surface

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a navigation bar. The code looks like this:

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="topnav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Overview</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In css I have the following code for the li elements:

```
ul.topnav li{
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    background-clip:padding-box;
    text-align:center;
    width:139px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;

    background-image:url(images/nav_normal.png);
    background-color:#CC33CC;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:9px 0 8px 0;
    margin:0;
    color:#6F5270;
    text-shadow:#FCF 0 1px;
}
ul.topnav li a{
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:auto;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-shadow:#903 0 1px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

It generates this following button:

[image: Different padding values]

The problem is the link-clickable area (shown in blue above) doesn't cover the entire surface of the button. So when I click on the edges of the button, it doesn't work. I tried to play with *padding* value but couldn't solve the problem. Is there an easy and efficient way to make the link cover the whole area of the button so that it works wherever on the button the user might click?

Comment: Tip, other than "display:inline;float:left;" put all styling on the A-tag and use display:block.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting `display: block;` in the CSS for `ul.topnav li a`.

Answer (score 3):

Make the `<a>` tag `display:block` and add the padding, width etc to the anchor.

```
ul.topnav li{
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}

ul.topnav li a{
    display: block;
    color:#6F5270;
    text-shadow:#FCF 0 1px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-image:url(images/nav_normal.png);
    background-clip:padding-box;
    background-color:#CC33CC;
    text-align:center;
    width:139px;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:9px 0 8px 0;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:auto;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-shadow:#903 0 1px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ul.topnav li a{
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    height:17px;
    line-height:17px;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:#903 0 1px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use only this

```
ul.topnav li a{
    display:inline-block;
}
```